# unix how delete directory named with dangerous name

Tags: unix, rm

Hello how to delete a directory named by error "*" ? It is dangerous!
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 31 16:04 *

Answer (score 0):

`rmdir '*'` seems to work. Note the single quotes. (You'll have to pre-delete its contents.)